# How to search Oracle table with a string key using Entity Framework 5 and the ODP.NET Managed Provider

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

My table is like this (pseudo code):
CREATE TABLE DOCUMENT_LOCATOR (DOCUMENT_ID VARCHAR2(6) PRIMARY KEY)

When using the latest ODP.NET Managed Driver v121.1.2 downloaded via NuGet, the following Entity Framework commands do NOT use the index:

```
context.DOCUMENT_LOCATOR.Find("ABC123");
context.DOCUMENT_LOCATOR.Find(EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode("ABC123"));
context.DOCUMENT_LOCATOR.FirstOrDefault(i => i.DOCUMENT_ID == "ABC123");
```

The following command does use the index:

```
context.DOCUMENT_LOCATOR.FirstOrDefault(i => i.DOCUMENT_ID == EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode("ABC123"));
```

Unfortunately, UPDATEs and DELETEs do not use the index, so they basically render EF/Oracle useless for large tables.  Has anyone figured out how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

After a fair amount of searching, I found a [very nice solution](http://www.johncoder.com/Post/EFCodeFirstDisableUnicodeforallStringProperties).  It sets all the string properties of all the entities to IsUnicode(false).  To use it, you simply add one line to the OnModelCreating method of your DbContext class:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ASSUMED_NAME_FILESMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ASSUMED_NAME_FILENAME_ONLYMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DOCUMENT_LOCATORMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IMS_IMAGE_TABLEMap());

        modelBuilder.DisableUnicodeForAllEntityStrings(this);
    }
```

As you can see, I changed the code to be an extension.  Here's my adapted code:

```
public static class DbModelBuilderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Disables unicode for all string properties on entities in the given context.
    /// MUST BE CALLED AFTER modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(map) CALLS.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Adapted from http://www.johncoder.com/Post/EFCodeFirstDisableUnicodeforallStringProperties
    /// </remarks>
    public static void DisableUnicodeForAllEntityStrings(this DbModelBuilder builder, DbContext context)
    {
        // Get all IDbSet<> properties from the context
        var entityTypes = from property in context.GetType().GetProperties()
                          where property.PropertyType.ImplementsInterface(typeof(IDbSet<>))
                          let entityType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
                          select entityType;

        // Disable Unicode support for each table
        foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
            DisableUnicodeForEntityStrings(builder, entityType);
    }
    private static void DisableUnicodeForEntityStrings(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder, Type entityType)
    {
        // Get all string properties with setters
        var stringProperties = from property in entityType.GetProperties()
                               where property.PropertyType == typeof(string)
                                   && property.CanWrite
                               select property;

        // Each table field must be varchar for now,
        // so take the string property & call IsUnicode(false).
        foreach (var property in stringProperties)
        {
            // Don't remove this line.
            // Lambda might not work without it.
            PropertyInfo prop = property;

            // Create the correct expression type,
            // should be Expression<Func<TModel, string>>
            var exprType = typeof(Expression<>)
                .MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>)
                .MakeGenericType(prop.ReflectedType, typeof(string)));

            // Find and execute the Entity() method,
            // using TModel generic parameter
            var obj = modelBuilder.GetType()
                .GetMethod("Entity")
                .MakeGenericMethod(prop.ReflectedType)
                .Invoke(modelBuilder, null);

            // Runtime Lambda expression to represent
            // something like Property(p => p.Suffix)
            ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(prop.ReflectedType, "p");
            var expression = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(pe, prop.Name), pe);

            // Find the Property method that takes an expression as a parameter
            // and then invoke it using the expression that was just built
            var p = obj.GetType()
                .GetMethod("Property", new[] { exprType })
                .Invoke(obj, new[] { expression });

            // If all goes well, we'll have a StringPropertyConfiguration.
            var propertyConfig = p as StringPropertyConfiguration;
            if (propertyConfig != null)
                propertyConfig.IsUnicode(false);
        }
    }
    public static bool ImplementsInterface(this Type value, Type interfaceType)
    {
        return value.GetInterface(interfaceType.FullName) != null;
    }
}
```